# In a simple graph with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges, if $m>\frac12n\sqrt{n+1}$ then the graph has a cycle of length $3$ or $4$

Tags: graph-theory

> Let's assume $G$ is a simple graph, having $n$ vertices and $m$ edges. What I want to prove is that if $$m > \frac12 n \sqrt{n+1}$$ then $G$ includes at least a cycle of length 3 or 4 (triangle or square).

*Note*: What I've tried is to make proof by contradiction, assuming there is a vertex $v$ being included in no square or triangle, but have not resulted in anything useful yet.

Comment: Is there some restriction on $n$?  For example, if $n=3$ we have $m \gt \frac{1}{2} 3 \sqrt{3+1}=\frac{1}{2} 3 \times 2 =3$.  However, if you have a simple graph with 3 vertices and 4 edges you will have a cycle of length 3 plus a leftover edge that doesn't have two associated vertices.  Just wanted to point that out - perhaps the definition of the problem needs to be double-checked.  I hope this helps.

Comment: @ad2004 The problem given in the question is the exact problem I’ve encountered and there is no additional condition. About your example, we can’t have a simple graph with 3 vertices have more than 3 edges, so I personally think because the question has stated “simple graph”, this example would not be a counterexample for the problem.

Comment: Have you tried looking on the dual graph?

Comment: @NeitherNor What if $G$ is not a planar graph?

Comment: Theorem 4.1 here gives the bound $m>\frac{1}2n(\sqrt{n}+1)$. It's not as tight as the OP's bound. https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.5167v2

Answer (score 1):

In fact, an even tighter bound holds:

> A graph of girth at least five with $n$ vertices has at most
> $\frac{1}2n\sqrt{n-1}$ edges.

The following proof is taken from page 8, theorem 2.2 in the following paper:

> Extremal graphs of girth five, Lazebnik et al (1993)
> [http://www.math.udel.edu/~lazebnik/papers/techrep.pdf](http://www.math.udel.edu/%7Elazebnik/papers/techrep.pdf)

**Preliminary definitions:**

-The **girth** of a graph is the length of the shortest cycle that it contains.

-The **diameter** of a graph is the maximum distance between any two vertices.

-Call a graph $G$ **extremal** if it has girth at least five and there does not exist any other graph of girth at least five with the same number of vertices and strictly fewer edges.

**Lemma 1:** Every extremal graph has diameter at most three.

**Proof of lemma 1:** *Let $x,y$ be vertices of distance at least four in an extremal graph. Then adding the edge $xy$ to the graph would produce another graph of girth five.*

Let $D_i$ be the number of unordered pairs of vertices whose distance is at most $i$ and $d(x)$ be the degree of the vertex $x$.

**Lemma 2:** In any girth of girth at least five, $D_2=\sum_{x\in V(G)}\binom{d(x)}2$

**Proof of lemma 2**: *Let $y,z$ be one of the $\binom{d(x)}2$ pairs of vertices adjacent to $x$. If $y$ were adjacent to $z$, we would have a triangle. If $y,z$ were also adjacent to some $x'$ then we would have a four-cycle.*

**Main statement:** Any extremal graph has at most $e=\frac{1}2n\sqrt{n-1}$ edges.

**Proof of main statement:**

From the lemmas, $\binom{n}2=D_1+D_2+D_3=e+\sum_{x\in V(G)}\binom{d(x)}2+D_3$.

Let $\overline{d}$ be the average degree of the graph and $\sigma^2=\sum_{x\in V(G)}(d(x)-\overline{d})^2$. Obviously $2e=\sum_{x\in V(G)}d(x)$ and $\overline{d}=2e/n$.

Then $\sum d(x)^2=\sigma^2-\sum \overline{d}^2-2\sum d\overline{d}=\sigma^2+4e^2/n$.

So $\binom{n}2=\sigma^2/2+2e^2/n+D_3$. If we take $\sigma^2=D_3=0$ then we get the desired upper bound on $e$.

Answer (score 1):

I'll present perhaps a "friendlier-looking" (though that is a matter of personal opinion) proof of the same statement that Angela pursues in their answer above; it isn't better, just a different presentation that you may prefer. Be warned, however -- you will have to fill-in some blanks for yourself along the way.

**Proposition.** Let $G$ be a graph of order $n$ and size $m$. If $m > \frac{1}{2}n\sqrt{n-1}$, $G$ has girth at most $4$.

**Proof.** Consider the number $\sum_{v \in V(G)}\binom{deg(v)}{2}$; it counts the number of triples of vertices $v_1, v_2, v_3$ such that $v_1$ is a neighbor of both $v_2$ and $v_3$ (why? Reading Angela's proof of lemma 2 will help). Under the assumption that $G$ hasn't any $3$- or $4$-cycles, we can obtain the inequality $$\sum_{v \in V(G)}\binom{deg(v)}{2} \leq \binom{n}{2} - m$$ quite easily (any pair of adjacent vertices has no common neighbor (else a triangle) and no pair of nonadjacent vertices has $\geq 2$ common neighbors (else a $C_4$)). If you prefer it in words, we are "bounding the number of common neighbors of a given pair of vertices."
To obtain the sharpest bound possible, we wish to minimize the number $\sum_{v \in V(G)}\binom{deg(v)}{2}$. As always, we're working with the Handshaking Lemma's constraint of $\sum_{v \in V(G)}deg(v) = 2m$, and we can easily observe that $\sum_{v \in V(G)}\binom{deg(v)}{2}$ is minimized by taking $deg(v) = 2m/n$ for each $v$ (sample some alternative ways to distribute the degrees to convince yourself of this fact). From here, it's all algebra; we have the inequality $$n(\frac{m}{n})(\frac{2m}{n-1}) \leq \frac{n(n-1)}{2} - m$$ which eventually simplifies to $$m \leq \frac{1}{2}n\sqrt{n-1},$$ the desired contradiction. $\square$

**Remark.** Of course, this proves something stronger than your desired statement. I couldn't think of an inequality which works out to be exactly what's given in your question, but it's quite possible that there is a more elementary method which proves your weaker result (which would probably be the method which the person who wrote the question had in mind).